# Overwrite json file in mongodb with python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

My current code doesn't overwrite the json stored in the MongoDB, instead it creates another document. I want it to overwrite. How do I do that?

Below is my current code

```
import json
import pymongo
import dns
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Making Connection
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<DBNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DBNAME>.y3vh0.mongodb.net/<DBNAME>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = myclient["PlayerPrices"]

Collection = db["Playstation"]

# Loading or Opening the json file
with open('players.json') as file:
    file_data = json.load(file)

if isinstance(file_data, list):
    Collection.insert_many(file_data)
else:
    Collection.insert_one(file_data)
    
print("Done")
```

Comment: you can use [collection.replace_one](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one)

Comment: @deadshot what should the "filter" tag be? collection.replace_one(filter?, file_data)

Comment: @deadshot Should I use the _id at the top of the collection like this: ```collection.replace_one('_id': 'ObjectId("5f5...."'```

Comment: yeah you can use `_id` field

Comment: @deadshot This code doesn't work: `Collection.replace_one({'_id': "ObjectId('5f5cdc551a462a76a876a490')"}, file_data)`

Is it something with the ' or the " inside the replace_one parenthesis?

Comment: can you share the sample json and sample document from db

Comment: Sure, here is the json file: https://pastebin.pl/view/d3e3c2fe
And here is a photo of the MongoDB: https://imgur.com/a/HzXike6
@deadshot

Comment: is `players.json` is a single document or multiple documents?

Comment: @deadshot A single

Comment: is that really a single document `players.json` has 1153 players

Comment: Yes it is @deadshot

Comment: don't pass `ObjectId` as a string

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, if you are going to find and update the specific document, it would be better to use the find_one_and_update() method.

https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-update-a-mongodb-document-in-python-356

I wish it would be helpful for you.

Comment: I dont need to update, all I need to do is replace. Does this method work for just replacing?

Comment: how it is best for replacing a document? and don't post link only answer add an example how this solves the OP's problem

Comment: It also works for replacing. If you want just to replace the document, there are other options as well. replace_one(), replace_many().